# how to destroy bootstrap modal window completely?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've made use of **modal window** for a wizard implementation which has around 4,5 steps. I need to destroy it completely after the **last step**(onFinish) and **OnCancel step without having a page refresh**. I can of course hide it, but hiding modal windows restores everything as such when i open up it again. Could anyone help me on this issue?

Thanks
Any hints answers are helpful for me.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or something similar? Might be able to do `$(modal_selector).remove()`.

Comment: thanks it works but it when we rev=invoke doesnt get invoked by modal.show()..then how to reinvoke it?

Comment: Yeah `remove` will really delete the modal, so it isn't openable again. Twitter Bootstrap's modal windows aren't really anything magical, so when you reopen a modal dialog you have to reset all the form elements manually (that's been my experience).

Comment: It depends on what you're displaying in the modal. Twitter Bootstrap only handles the displaying of the modal, whatever is in it is your responsibility.

Comment: Sir I am asking that how invoke, close and reinvoke Modal

Comment: I do this by having a web service in the background feed me the HTML on demand using jquery/json, then you could simply remove the HTML once you are done with it. This would allow you to do it without refreshing the page.

Comment: There are a few different approaches here.  I would like to point out two things that are important for Bootstrap V3.  Firstly, if you are using $(this).data('modal',null), you need to replace 'modal' with 'bs.modal'.  Secondly, I could not get it to trigger with the hidden event, but it worked fine with the hide event.

Comment: Why is anything Javascript with Bootstrap such a royal pain.

Comment: Use jquery's .clone(), load() and replaceWith() to save and restore the dialog html data

Answer (score 127, accepted):

if is bootstrap 3 you can use:

```js
$("#mimodal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
});
```

Comment: This was exactly the piece of magic I needed without digging into the bootstrap core code. Thank you!

Comment: As every other answers, this does not seems to remove the backdrop.

Comment: @htulipe The approach is right but it will not work with transition effects on the modal. You'll need to remove .fade class from modal to get it work.

Comment: @drillingman: +1 that worked for me: `$("#mimodal").removeClass('fade').modal('hide')`

Comment: The only thing in BS3 that worked for me was: `$(this).html("");`

Comment: did nothing, the dialog was there in the DOM as it is, only hidden. I'm using bootstrap 3.2.0

Comment: Doesn't remove event handlers etc, so specifically fails to answer the question for BS 3 at least.

Removing the HTML doesn't cut it either - that's *not* the modal and may well contain HTML you need.

Comment: if I'm not using JQuery, how do I do this?

Comment: @UrielArvizu Bootstrap JS requires JQuery so if you're using this modal you have JQuery available

Comment: @sync AngularJS, as far as I know, uses a super lightweight version of JQuery if no reference for it is included into the project, honestly I'm not a big fan of JQuery so for AngularJS to acknowledge people like me is great, they only include a small percent of JQuery functions, the rest is pure JS.

Comment: Be careful, if you delete only data, events remain associated with the old modal, I advise you to delete it entirely and recreate from the HTML.

Comment: How exactly do you delete it entirely? @Loenix

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was using `$(this).remove();` instead of `$(this).data('bs.modal', null);` and then adding after the function `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/41t5vf1p/

Comment: This worked for me $(this).find(".modal-body").html("");
Because I want to use modal again but with another content and $(this).html("") destroyed everything and new modal didn't shown!

Comment: doesn't work for me. the only thing remotely working is Vatsal's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51947610/3907258

Answer (score 41):

*NOTE: This solution works only for Bootstrap before version 3. For a Bootstrap 3 answer, refer to [this one by user2612497](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18169689/177710).*

What you want to do is:

```
$('#modalElement').on('hidden', function(){
    $(this).data('modal', null);
});
```

that will cause the modal to initialize itself every time it is shown.  So if you are using remote content to load into the div or whatever, it will re-do it everytime it is opened.  You are merely destroying the modal instance after each time it is hidden.

Or whenever you want to trigger the destroying of the element (in case it is not actually every time you hide it) you just have to call the middle line:

```
$('#modalElement').data('modal', null);
```

Twitter bootstrap looks for its instance to be located in the data attribute, if an instance exists it just toggles it, if an instance doesn't exist it will create a new one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This actually does work however in a slightly different manner    `$("#modalElement").removeData("modal");`    I am using Bootstrap 2.3.1 and jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: If you use Bootstrap 3, you must listen to the `hidden.bs.modal` instead of the `hidden` event. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 20):

For 3.x version

```
$( '.modal' ).modal( 'hide' ).data( 'bs.modal', null );
```

For 2.x version (risky; read comments below)
When you create bootstrap modal three elements on your page being changed. So if you want to completely rollback all changes, you have to do it manually for each of it.

```
$( '.modal' ).remove();
$( '.modal-backdrop' ).remove();
$( 'body' ).removeClass( "modal-open" );
```

Comment: Using manual steps is a risky approach, as the Bootstrap code might get changed and you might miss some aspects, then. For examply, at least in Bootstrap 3.2 `style="padding-right: 17px;"` will be set on the `body` as well to account for the hiding scrollbar. Bottom line: use Bootstraps API which in v3 would be `$('.modal').modal('hide').data('bs.modal', null);`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. This was written for 2.x version. Updated.

Comment: if your dynamically injecting data to modal and you remove all of the second part of your answer it will strip much more than needed. Beyond the point of reusing modal. If it helps I suggest using your specific class.remove();

Answer (score 15):

You can completely destroy a modal without page reloading by this way.

```
$("#modal").remove();
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$( 'body' ).removeClass("modal-open");
```

**but it will completely remove modal from your html page. After this modal hide show will not work.**

Comment: .remove() removes it completely . And .show() doesnt work any more . What do I do initialize it again ?

Comment: Since creating bootstrap modal make changes to `body` suggested solution will not roll back all changes.

Comment: This won't work, because the backdrop will be stuck, why did it even get upvoted?

Answer (score 11):

I have tried accepted answer but it isn't seems working on my end and I don't know how the accepted answer suppose to work.

```
$('#modalId').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).remove();
})
```

This is working perfectly fine on my side. BS Version > 3

Comment: This leaves a gray backdrop as well leaving the web page unusable!!

Comment: Works perfectly on BS4, and the backdrop gets automatically removed as well as it picks up to the modal remove event.

Answer (score 4):

The power of jQuery. `$(selector).modal('hide').destroy();` will first remove sinds you might have the sliding affect and then removes the element completely, however if you want the user to be able to open the modal again after you finished the steps. you might just wanna update only the settings you wanna have reseted so for reseting all the inputs in your modal this would look like the following:

```
$(selector).find('input, textarea').each(function(){
   $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is an answer? question clearly is asking for removing `bootstrap modal` which neither text nor the example answers that!

Answer (score 4):

Also works on bootstrap 4.x

```
$('#modal_ID').modal( 'hide' ).data( 'bs.modal', null );
```

Comment: This disposes the modal but leaves a gray backdrop which makes the web page unusable

Comment: In which bootstrap version did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

bootstrap 3 + jquery 2.0.3:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#myModal').removeData();
})
```

Comment: Since creating bootstrap modal make changes to `body` suggested solution will not roll back all changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an iframe in your modal, you can remove its content by the following code:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
   $(this).find('iframe').html("");
   $(this).find('iframe').attr("src", "");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to use the [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method of jQuery. It creates a copy of your element, and that's what you want : a copy of your first unaltered modal, that you can replace at your wish : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/8XCps/)

```js
var myBackup = $('#myModal').clone();

// Delegated events because we make a copy, and the copied button does not exist onDomReady
$('body').on('click','#myReset',function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide').remove();
    var myClone = myBackup.clone();
    $('body').append(myClone);
});
```

The markup I used is the most basic, so you just need to bind on the right elements / events, and you should have your wizard reset.

**Be careful** to bind with [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), or rebind at each reset the inner elements of your modal so that each new modal behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

From what i understand, you don't wanna remove it, nor hide it ? Because you might wanna reuse it later ..but don't want it to have the old content if ever you open it up again ?

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you wanna use it as a dynamic template just do something like

```
$(selector).modal({show: true})

....

$(selector).modal({show: false})
$(".modal-body").empty()

....

$(".modal-body").append("new stuff & text")
$(selector).modal({show: true})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(this).data('bs.modal', null).remove();
});

//Just add .remove(); 
//Bootstrap v3.0.3
```

Comment: While this code may, in fact, be a solution to the problem, it is generally a good idea to include an explanation of what it does when you answer a question.

Comment: Ok. I was in a hurry... anyway add ".remove();" for remove all reference and html code of your bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

`this.$el.modal().off();`

Answer (score 2):

This completely removes the modal from the DOM , is working for the "appended" modals as well .

## #pickoptionmodal is the id of my modal window.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal','#pickoptionmodal',function(e){

e.preventDefault();

$("#pickoptionmodal").remove();

});
```

Comment: After this, can the modal re-initialized?

Comment: @rahim.nagori as it writes in the description is deleting the modal from the DOM , you can re-add it ... is not closing modal , is deleting him , the thread is about destroy modal window completely.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same scenario where I would open a new modal on a button click. Once done, I want to completely remove it from my page... I use remove to delete the modal.. On button click I would check if modal exists , and if true I would destroy it and create a new modal ..

```
$("#wizard").click(function() {
    /* find if wizard is already open */
    if($('.wizard-modal').length) {
        $('.wizard-modal').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me on BS4:

```
let $modal = $(this);
$modal.modal('hide').on("hidden.bs.modal", function (){
    $modal.remove();
});
```

we remove the modal after it is completely hidden.
from BS doc:

> hidden.bs.modal:  This event is fired when the modal has finished being
> hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

Answer (score 0):

If modal shadow remains darker and not going for showing more than one modal then this will be helpful

```
$('.modal').live('hide',function(){
    if($('.modal-backdrop').length>1){
        $('.modal-backdrop')[0].remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Live is outdated, to be replaced with on and the [0] on the element you're targeting isn't necessary if you're using jQuery. Also, if you remove the backdrop entirely, note you may have to add it back...Try:

`$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function(e) {
    if ($('.modal-backdrop').length) {
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use same modal for different link clicks. I just replaced the html content with empty "" of the modal in hidden callback.

Answer (score 0):

only this worked for me

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
    $('selector').val('');
});
```

It is safe forcing selectors to make them blank since bootstrap and jquery version may be the reason of this problem

Comment: This leaves a gray backdrop as well leaving the web page unusable!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$('.modal-backdrop').removeClass('in');
$('#myDiv').removeClass('in');
```

The dialog and backdrop went away, but they came back the next time I clicked the button.

Answer (score 0):

It works for Bootstrap v3.3.6

```
$('#dialog').modal()
.on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    // Some Code
}).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    // Some Code
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#dialog").off();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Single line complete removal on hide ( ES6 )

`$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', (e)=>e.currentTarget.remove());`

Answer (score 0):

With ui-router this may be an option for you.  It reloads the controller on close so reinitializes the modal contents before it fires next time.

```
$("#myModalId").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $state.reload();  //resets the modal
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to destroy the modal right after it is closed through a button click, and so I came up with the following.

```
$("#closeModal").click(function() {
    $("#modal").modal('hide').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#modal").remove();
    });
});
```

Note that this works with Bootstrap 3.

Comment: This leaves a gray backdrop as well leaving the web page unusable!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5, this works like a charm for me

```
const modal = document.querySelector('#myModal');

const modalElement = new bootstrap.Modal(modal);
modalElement.show();

modalElement._element.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
    modalElement._element.remove();
});

// hide the modal, which will then trigger the event above and destroy it
modalElement.hide();
```

Answer (score -4):

I don't know how this may sound but this work for me...........

```
$("#YourModalID").modal('hide');
```

Comment: Downvoted because it just hides the modal what clearly wasn't asked.