# How to reset form body in bootstrap modal box?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, refresh

I am looking for a way to **clear all elements** found within an **HTML form** contained **inside a Bootstrap modal** *without* refreshing the page.

Currently:

The user enters data and closes the modal.

When the user re-opens the modal, the **previously entered data still remains**.

How can I completely clear all elements within the form during the **close event** of the modal dialog so that when the user re-opens it, they always get fresh clean inputs & etc?

Answer (score 88):

In Bootstrap 3 you can reset your form after your modal window has been closed as follows:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
});
```

Comment: But after closing the modal, how can I make the dismissal message fade?

Comment: ... and if the event is not firing at all, make sure you put this code before you instantiate the modal http://stackoverflow.com/a/25466850/2436549

Comment: not working for me D: I hate when simple solutions don't work xd, but when this has to be done manually, jumping into the inspector and figuring out what classes are being applied on fields on errors and removing them with a  simple function may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 15):

You can make a JavaScript function to do that:

```
$.clearInput = function () {
        $('form').find('input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=number], input[type=email], textarea').val('');
};
```

and then you can call that function each time your modal is hidden:

```
$('#Your_Modal').on('hidden', function () {
        $.clearInput();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I went with a slightly modified version of @shibbir's answer:

```
// Clear form fields in a designated area of a page
$.clearFormFields = function(area) {
  $(area).find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"],textarea,select').val('');
};
```

Called this way:

```
$('#my-modal').on('hidden', function(){
  $.clearFormFields(this)
});
```

Comment: I am not getting the hidden even fired.

Comment: shams, my approach was for Bootstrap 2, based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13423830/550712). Looks like it's changed in Bootstrap 3. Maybe bart's answer works for you? Otherwise for general Bootstrap modal issues, you might want to create your own question.

Answer (score 4):

If you using ajax to load modal's body such way and want to be able to reload it's content

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="./add">Add</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="./edit/id">Modify</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Content will be loaded here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

use

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the empty values to the input fields when modal is hiding.

```
$('#Modal_Id').on('hidden', function () {
   $('#Form_Id').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: For bootstrap 5, replace **hidden** with **hidden.bs.modal**

Answer (score 1):

Mark Berry's answer worked fine here. I just add to split the previous code:

```
$.clearFormFields = function(area) {
  $(area).find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"],textarea,select').val('');
};
```

to:

```
$.clearFormFields = function(area) {
                $(area).find('input#name').val('');
                $(area).find('input#phone').val("");
                $(area).find('input#email').val("");
                $(area).find('select#topic').val("");
                $(area).find('textarea#description').val("");
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variance of need to reset body to original content. It doesn't deal with a form but I feel it might be of some use. If the original content was a ton of html, it is very difficult to string out the html and store it to a variable. Javascript does not take kindly to the line breaks that VS 2015/whatever allows. 
So I store original ton of html in default modal like this on page load:

```
var stylesString = $('#DefaultModal .modal-body').html();
```

Which allows me to to reuse this content when original default button for modal is pressed (there are other buttons that show other content in same modal).

```
$("#btnStyles").click(function () {
    //pass the data in the modal body adding html elements
    $('#DefaultModal .modal-body').html(stylesString);
 $('#DefaultModal').modal('show');
})
```

If I put an alert for the styleString variable it would have an endless string of all the html with no breaks but does it for me and keeps it out of VS editor.

Here is how it looks in Visual Studio inside default modal. Saved in the string variable whether automatic (.html) or by hand in VS, it would be one big line:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modalbody">


    <div class="whatdays"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">All Styles</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/ballroom.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Ballroom</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/blues.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Blues</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/contra.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Contra</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/countrywestern.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Country</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/english-country.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">English Country</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/israeli.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Israeli</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/lindyhop.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Lindy Hop/Swing</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/miscvariety.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Misch/Variety</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/neo-square.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Neo-Square</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/polka.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Polka</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/salsa.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Salsa</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/scottish.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Scottish</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/square.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Square</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/tango.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Tango</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/waltz.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Waltz</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/wcswing.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">WCS</span></div>
    <div class="whatdays" style="background-image: url('../../Responsive/zyedeco-gator.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;"><span style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;border:2px solid yellow;">Zydeco/Cajun</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find your form and clear before it opens!

```
    $modal = $('#modal');
    $modal.find('form')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score -1):

The below solution solved my problem and also kept the default values

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { 
  $(this).find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"],textarea,select').each(function() { 
    if (this.defaultValue != '' || this.value != this.defaultValue) {
         this.value = this.defaultValue; 
    } else { this.value = ''; }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your code, so that it is useful for new readers.

Comment: Why over-complicate things if you can just use $(this).find('form')[0].reset();