# bootstrap jquery show.bs.modal event won't fire

Tags: modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery

i'm using the modal example from the bootstrap 3 docs. the modal works. however i need to access the show.bs.modal event when it fires. for now i'm just trying:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
   alert('hi')
})
```

Nothing happens, the event does not fire. What am I doing wrong??? This doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 134):

use this:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#myModal', function () {
  alert('hi');
})
```

Comment: This solved my problem. But I placed it outside the document.ready function. When I placed within document.ready, It was not working. Might help someone.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it works perfectly with dynamically created ajax modals via `$(data).modal('show');`.

Comment: This would fire for each modal you have on the document. To target only specific modal you could use `$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'my-modal-id') {
        alert('hi');
    }
});`. Id here comes from `<div class="modal fade" id="my-modal-id">`

Comment: @przno No it wouldn't, the second argument is the selector which specifies the element.

Comment: When you use `$(document).on(...` you attach your listener to *document* context, and its no matter if your target elemnts is exists or not. You should add event name as first argument and callback fanction as last, but you can add a query selector as second argument

Answer (score 88):

Make sure you put your `on('shown.bs.modal')` before instantiating the modal to pop up

```
$("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () { 
    alert('Hi');
});
$("#myModal").modal('show'); //This can also be $("#myModal").modal({ show: true });
```

or

```
$("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () { 
    alert('Hi');
}).modal('show');
```

To focus on a field, it is better to use the `shown.bs.modal` in stead of `show.bs.modal` but maybe for other reasons you want to hide something the the background or set something right before the modal starts showing, use the `show.bs.modal` function.

Comment: @kjdion84 - there where you create them, you should bind the events. `var amodal = $("<div modal... />"); amodal.on(...,myfunc).modal('show');

Comment: You don't have to bind any events if you use `$(document).on()`.

Comment: ^This solves my problem. Also, `show.bs.modal` is different from `shown.bs.modal`. The former fires when the modal is about to show. The latter when it has been shown. Big different.

Comment: @KUMAR it is the event which bootstrap is calling when you call `.modal('show')`. There are four events it calls for modals: [`show.bs.modal`, `shown.bs.modal`, `hide.bs.modal`, `hidden.bs.modal`] - show is when it is going to show, shown when it is showing, the same for hide and hidden. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-events

Answer (score 27):

Wrap your function in `$(document).ready(function() { })`, or more simply, `$(function() {`. In CoffeeScript, this would look like

```
$ ->
  $('#myModal').on 'show.bs.modal', (event)->
```

Without it, the JavaScript is executing before the document loads, and `#myModal` is not part of the DOM yet. Here is the [Bootstrap reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

Comment: This is most likely correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal','.modal', function () {

/// TODO EVENTS

});
```

Comment: somehow this was the most helpful answer to me. it seems like working with `.modal` instead of referencing the modals id was the solution... thanks!

Comment: This is the best answer as it is nonspecific and will trigger on any modal being shown rather than when just a set modal triggers.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   alert('hi');
});
```

Using `shown` instead of `show` also make sure you have your semi colons at the end of your function and alert.

Comment: Both 'show.bs.modal' and 'shown.bs.modal' should work for my purposes, they are both listed as valid events in the bootstrap docs. still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you verified that your jQuery is working e.g. $(document).ready(function(){alert('test');});

Comment: yes if i put an alert outside the show event, just within document.ready, then it fires.

Comment: Try making an example of you code here http://bootply.com/new and see if it works.  If it doesn't work share your link and I can take a look at it.

Comment: Make sure you have your `bootstrap.js` file loaded.

Comment: thx for your help trevor -- it is rly still a mystery to me why it won't work. everything on my site is just like in your example. and i have a lot of experience with jquery/bootstrap. something weird and underlying must be going on but i don't even know where to look.

Comment: bootstrap.js is definitely loaded

Comment: Okay no problem, you could share your html and or webpage if you think it would help.  Good luck figuring out what is going on.

Comment: sure, here is the dev site - it's not cleaned up so disregard a lot of it -- the only thing i care about is that the alert('hi') work when the modal is fired. i just inserted the example to test.

Comment: The requested URL /gunnar_bootstrap/didyouseethis/js/application.js was not found on this server.

Comment: @BassJobsen He is referencing application.js twice in his html one of them is loading the correct file.  The other it's not found.. Would that cause the issue?

Comment: Thanks @Trevor. It worked for me too. I was including 2 jquery.js. :-p

Answer (score 8):

Add this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal','.modal', function () {
         // DO EVENTS
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Similar thing happened to me and I have solved using setTimeout.

Bootstrap is using the following timeout to complete showing:

> c.TRANSITION_DURATION=300,c.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION=150,

So using more than 300 must work and for me 200 is working:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Do something if necessary
    }, 300);                        
})
```

Comment: This is what I have been searching for! Thanks for pointing out the transition duration of the bootstrap! Kudos :D Even 150 works too :)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was missing the .modal-dialog div

Doesn't fire event: shown.bs.modal

```
<div id="loadingModal" class="modal fade">
  <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

Does fire event: shown.bs.modal

```
<div id="loadingModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">      
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with bootstrap4.
The solution was to add it inside the jQuery document ready() function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
       alert('hi')
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you - being a JS noob, had to wade through a ton of related questions/answers to find that this solved my problem of the modal, for whatever reason, only firing hte event handler on the second load (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339958/bootstrap-modal-dialogs-shown-bs-modal-event-doesnt-fire)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue. For me it was that i loaded jquery twice in this order:

1. Loaded jQuery
2. Loaded Bootstrap
3. Loaded jQuery again

When jQuery was loaded the second time it somehow broke the references to bootstrap and the modal opened but the on('shown.bs..') method never fired.

Comment: Thanks. I had jquery loaded on the _Layout.cshtml and on my view on ASP.NET. I took me hours till I flow by your comment.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when code might been executed before and it's not showing up so you can add timeout() for it tp fire.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        alert("Hi");
      },1000); 
    });
```

Comment: `1000` is not enough, you can put `999999` to be sure everything is loaded

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar but different problem and still unable to work when I use $('#myModal').  I was able to get it working when I use $(window).

My other problem is that I found that the show event would not fire if I stored my modal div html content in a javascript variable like.

```
var content="<div id='myModal' ...";
$(content).modal();
$(window).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  alert('show test');
});
```

the event never fired because it didn't occur

my fix was to include the divs in the html body

```
<body>
    <div id='myModal'>
       ...
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#myModal).modal();
        $(window).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            alert('show test');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember to put the script after the call of "js/bootstrap", not before.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you are loading jQuery before you use Bootstrap. Sounds basic, but I was having issues catching these modal events and turns out the error was not with my code but that I was loading Bootstrap before jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this doesn't work if:

1) you have an error in the java script code before your line with `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal'...)`. To troubleshoot put an alert message before the line to see if it comes up when you load the page. To resolve eliminate JSs above to see which one is the problem

2) Another problem is if you load up the JS in wrong order. For example you can have the `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal'...)` part before you actually load JQuery.js. In that case your call will be ignored, so first in the HTML (view page source to be sure) check if the script link to JQuery is above your modal `onShow` call, otherwise it will be ignored. To troubleshoot put an alert inside the on show an one before. If you see the one before and not the one inside the onShow function it is clear that the function cannot execute. If the spelling is right more than likely your call to JQuery.js is not made or it is made after the `onShow` part

Comment: This helped me - `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal'...)` needs to be after JQuery is loaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you really use the **bootstrap** jquery modal and not another jquery modal.

Wasted way too much time on this...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was how travelsize comment.. The order of imports between bootstrap.js and jquery. Because I'am using the template Metronic and doesn't check before

Answer (score 0):

i used jQuery's event delegation /bubbling... that worked for me. See below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function () {
                alert('hi loo');
            })
```

very good info  too: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

The popular solution to put a `setTimeout` could work in some case, but is a **terrible** solution. I was myself using it amongst wraping it in `$(document).ready()` off course (but it never helped), but I was never able to have a reliable solution. Some browser/system take more time than other, and sometime `1000ms` was not enough. And I was tired searching why the `$(document).ready()` wasn't helping, so :

**I took a different approach.**

I make the subscription to modal events when I need to use the modal for the first time.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ShowModal()">Open my modal</a>
```

and on the JS side :

```
function ShowModal() {
    InitModalEventsOnce();
    $('#MyModal').modal('show');
}

var InitModalEventsIsDone = false; // Flag to keep track of the subscribtion

function InitModalEventsOnce() {

    if (!InitModalEventsIsDone) {
        InitModalEventsIsDone = true;

        $('#MyModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            // something
        })

        $('#MyModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            // something
        });
    }
}
```

And that's it! The only reliable solution I found.

Comment: You can also do `$('#MyModal').off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal' function(){..});` This can be helpful if you need to change any behaviors based on the modal being shown as opposed to only defining the event handler one time.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
let mymodal=$('#myModal');
mymodal.on('show.bs.modal', function () 
{
    alert('hi')
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Native JavaScript event listener work:

```
$('#myModal')[0].addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', () => { 
    alert('hi');
});
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('myModal').addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', () => {   
    alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Below are the granular details:

show.bs.modal works while model dialog loading
shown.bs.modal worked to do any thing after loading. post rendering