# How to pass data to a textarea inside a bootstrap modal when clicking on a table's cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a table where I want allow a user edit information. One cell of the table contains text. Here is part of the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table_id">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        @foreach($events as $event)
            <td>{{$event->Event}}</td>
            <td><div id="notes-{{$event->id}}">{{$event->notes}}</div></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Should the user click on the row "notes", a bootstrap modal appears to allow the user make changes.

```
$('[id^="notes"]').on("click", function(){
    var input_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var previousValue = $('#'+input_id).html(); console.log('clicked! The current notes are: '+previousValue);
    var result = input_id.split('-');
    var notes_id = result[1];
    console.log('The event id selected is: '+notes_id);

    /*Open a modal*/
    $('#modal-notes').modal('show');

});
```

So far, I have managed to show the bootstrap modal, however, i don't know how to pass the data `previousValue` (retrieved from the database) into the textarea of the modal. `previousValue` has the text retrieved from the database.

The modal looks like the folowing:

```
<div id="modal-notes" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit event's notes</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" id="form-notes-event" name="form-notes-event" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Edit data</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="observations" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Notes</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="observations" name="observations"></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block">Clic on save button when done.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form> 

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

How do I pass the `previousValue` to the textarea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

upon showing, set the text:

```
/*Open a modal*/
$('#modal-notes').modal('show');
$('#modal-notes').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).find('#observations').text(previousValue);
});
```

Comment: try instead of $(this).find('#observations').text(previousValue); like follows:

$('#observations').text(previousValue);

Comment: I have set a `console.log('modal is open')` just after `$(this).find("#observations")` and the message is not shown. However, if I console.log when the modal buttons (cancel, update) are clicked, the console.log works when these buttons are clicked. It seems that the `on('bs.shown.modal')` is not working

Comment: AHHH, i see, it should be `shown.bs.modal` instead ;-) As explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25466850/1883256

Comment: true! i've set the event wrongly! will update for future references.