# Modal hidden action is not being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to use [the Hidden event on modals](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalthing" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
              <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
               //etc
              </form>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my javascript is:

```
$('#modalthing').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('test');
})
```

But my code is just nog executing the console.log

Am I missing something here? I got the code from the official bootstrap documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close) but I cant for the life of me figure out why it isnt triggering the event.

Comment: Is bootstrap.js loaded on your page?

Comment: @Mokkun Yes. My modal opens and closes but the event is not triggered.

Comment: Hmm did you try putting your function inside a $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: Where have you instanciated your modal? As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279629/bootstrap-jquery-show-bs-modal-event-wont-fire) you need to put the listener before you the part where you close it. If that's not it, then still check that question. I'm sure you'll find an answer there.

Comment: @Chris the modal opens through a button: `<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalthing"> click here</button>` This button is after the modal.

Comment: A working example, FYR. https://jsfiddle.net/0jgbbqvv/

Comment: Have you tried: `$('#modalthing').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modalthing', function (e) {
    console.log('test');
})`

Comment: @Chris yes I tried that. Didnt work.

Comment: Have you tried opening your modal like this : <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="$('#modalthing').modal('toggle')">Click me</button>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use data-dismiss attribute in closer buttons like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

I tried it on w3Schools editor and it executed.

Comment: I have that but it's still not triggering.