# update modal UI before opening the modal

Tags: r, shiny

From the second time on when you click the button that opens the modal the modal opens showing the old data at first and then the update of the render-function is triggered.

```
library(shiny)

showMyModal <- function() {
  showModal(
    modalDialog(
      verbatimTextOutput("mytext"),
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Dismiss"),
      )
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("openDialog", "Open dialog")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$openDialog, {
    showMyModal()
  })
  
  output$mytext <- renderPrint({
    input$openDialog
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a smart way to first update the modal UI and only afterwards opening the modal? I am looking for a way that the modal does not show outdated data before it gets refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach utilizing my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245681/observe-modal-easy-closing-in-shiny/75927136#75927136).

The following is blocking the display of your `modalDialog` until the modal has been (re)rendered:

```
library(shiny)

showMyModal <- function() {
  showModal(
    conditionalPanel("input.modal_visible == true",
                     modalDialog(
                       verbatimTextOutput("mytext"),
                       footer = tagList(
                         modalButton("Dismiss"),
                       )
                     )
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(HTML(
    "$(document).on('shown.bs.modal','#shiny-modal', function () {
       Shiny.setInputValue(id = 'modal_visible', value = true);
      });
     $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal','#shiny-modal', function () {
       Shiny.setInputValue(id = 'modal_visible', value = false);
     });"
  )),
  actionButton("openDialog", "Open dialog")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$openDialog, {
    showMyModal()
  })
  
  output$mytext <- renderPrint({
    input$openDialog
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```