# jquery getting the data-id from delete button and showing id in modal

Tags: jquery

I cant get the data-id attribute value to show in the modal when button is clicked

Here is my button:-

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="delcompanybtn" data-href="/deletecompany.php?companyid=' + data[0] + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" data-id=' + data[0] + '" ></a>
```

Here is my `Jquery` code:-

```
$('#delcompanybtn').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
var companyid = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
$('#showcompanyid').html(companyid);
});
```

Here is my modal body code:-

```
<div class="modal-body">
Delete Company ID : <span id="showcompanyid"></span> ?
</div>
```

Silly little things like this just bug me, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked that the `show.bs.modal` event actually works? I remember having issues with this in the past where it didn't. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279629/bootstrap-jquery-show-bs-modal-event-wont-fire)

Comment: What is `data-id=' + data[0] + '"`? And consider using `$(this).attr("data-id")` instead of `$(e.relatedTarget)`.

Comment: its in a datatables row..
the data[0] works fine as it displays the relevant ID when I hover over it and also the relevant href url works as it contains the ID .. i just cant get it to display in the span in the modal

Comment: It's missing a quotation mark as well.

Comment: @Matt yes the modal fires

Comment: If you're positive the event is firing, then try `$(this)` instead of `$(e.relatedTarget)`.

Comment: tried and still no joy have also removed the " but still same , no errors in console either

Comment: try this -> `$(this).data("id")` and also fix this-> `data-id="' + data[0] + '"`

Comment: @ShailParas still no difference

Answer (score 0):

solved :

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var companyid = $(this).data("id");
  $(this).find('#showcompanyid').html($(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id'));
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```