# JQuery shown.bs.modal won't fire

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This code is used to `EDit` the present `record` in the `Database` when I click the `fa fa-pencil`  icon. it shows a model.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".Edit-modal" class="Edit disciplinaryActionReview" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;">
<span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">
</span></a>
```

**This is Modal**

```
<div class="modal Edit-modal" id="myModel">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 1200px">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Items Information</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" id="EditHiddenID">
                        <label for="EditIdentification">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Edittitle" id="Edittitle">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default mright" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="saveChanges">Save changes</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

**but the `Modal` didn't show `alert`.**

```
$("#myModel").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
      alert("hi");
    });
```

**CODE:**

```js
$("#myModel").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
  alert("hi");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".Edit-modal" class="Edit disciplinaryActionReview" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;">
  <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"> Click Here!
</span></a>

<div class="modal Edit-modal" id="myModel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 90vw">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Items Information</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" id="EditHiddenID">
              <label for="EditIdentification">Title</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Edittitle" id="Edittitle">
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default mright" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="saveChanges">Save changes</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: Can you create a simple demo to reproduce this issue on jsfiddle or in the main post?

Comment: Also, have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19279629/1823841

Comment: @palaѕн I didn't know how to create demo here

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @palaѕн i will do it

Comment: I have added it for you, since this is your first time. But, it seems `shown.bs.modal` is working fine here. Maybe you are miisng something in your code.

Comment: @palaѕн i don't know why it not working on my localhost.

Comment: You can test it by creating new html page in your localhost and add this code, if it works then it means some issue is there on the current page only, not in the localhost. May be you are adding the modal html content dynamically or maybe it is partial view.

Comment: @palaѕн ok i will check it