# TwitterBootstrapMvc (3rd): modal dialog state

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Modal dialogs to submit new records (Asp.Net, MVC).

```
<div id="modal-dlg" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"></div>
<div id="banner-add">
   <a class="btn-default  btn" data-toggle="modal" href="@Url.Action("BannerSlideNewModal", "Account", new { Model.Id })" data-target="#modal-dlg" target="profile-banner">Add</a>
</div>
```

On form submit, after data processing, I hide current dialog:

```
form.submit(function() {
    button.attr('disabled', true).text('Please wait ...');
    // call service to update/add record
    if ($(this).valid()) {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(
    {
        success: function(data) {
            .....
            $('#' + context.id).modal('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, when I open modal dialog again, I want to see blank fields for new entry, but all fields are assigned from previous entry. How I can initialize each time new modal dialog instead of reusing same one?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to call form.reset()?

Comment: You can clear each field's value manually:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827262/how-to-reset-form-body-in-bootstrap-modal-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset your form with `reset()`:

```
form.submit(function() {
    button.attr('disabled', true).text('Please wait ...');
    // call service to update/add record
    if ($(this).valid()) {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(
    {
        success: function(data) {
            .....
            $('#' + context.id).modal('hide');
            form.reset();
        }
    });
});
```