# How to reset the bootstrap modal when it gets closed and open it fresh again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list box in the bootstrap modal and a button.
When the button is clicked a new button gets rendered inside a div in the modal.
When I close the modal and reopen it, the last operation performed on the modal like the button rendered earlier is still present in the modal.

How do reset the modal so that when the modal is opened again, the button is not present and user can again select the option from the list box and click on the button to render a new button and so on.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="myModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span
          ><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select Language</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit_form">Submit</button>

        <div class="modal-body1">
          <div id="placeholder-div1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <script>
          $("#submit_form").on("click", function () {
            $(".modal-body1").html("<h3>test</h3>");
          });
        </script>

        <script>
          $(function () {
            $(".modal-footer").click(function () {
              $(".modal").modal("hide");
            });
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

-- Update ---

Why doesn't this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
      console.log("Modal hidden");
      $("#placeholder-div1").html("");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Just reset any content manually when modal is hidden:

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    $(".modal-body1").html("");
});
```

There is more events. More about them [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    $(".modal-body1").html("Where did he go?!?!?!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class='modal-body1'>
          <h3>Close and open, I will be gone!</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No errors in developer tools console. The function is not getting called when i click close button or click anywhere outside

Comment: Thanks. I See it is running perfectly here. I don't know whats the problem with my rails app. I changed jquery and bootstrap version and copy pasted this code and it doesn't work in my application. No error indication in console. document.ready is getting called but hidden.bs.modal event is not getting captured.

Comment: @yardpenalty there is no difference to my answer and it's not improvement. You can put anything inside your hidden HTML

Comment: Im sorry I mispoke @Justinas. When you have remote modal this method works perfectly because it clears the remote content. And on the next request it will reload `.modal-body` from the remote content. If you have an inline modal clearing the `.modal-body` it is not a good idea. What I did for inline modals was used a toggle approach with a `hidden` class inside the `.modal-body`. For instance, I have `<div class="loading hidden"><span class="caption">Loading...</span><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="loading"></div>` and then a `<div class="context hidden">actual content</div>`.  Upvoted btw

Comment: This solution did not work for me. But below code worked for me.

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
              jQuery(this).data('bs.modal', null);
        });
 });

Comment: @wangsir Depends what you put in `.html("Where did he go?!?!?!")`

Comment: @Justinas Then, you need to refill the body every time when `calling modal.show()`, I cant accept this method.

Answer (score 48):

Tried it and working well

```
$('#MyModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
})
```

`reset` is dom build-in funtion, you can also use `$(this).find('form')[0].reset();`

And Bootstrap's modal class exposes a few events for hooking into modal functionality, detail [at here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

> `hide.bs.modal`   This event is fired immediately when the hide instance
>   method has been called.
>
> `hidden.bs.modal` This event is fired when the modal has finished being
>   hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Other solutions like adding/removing the modal, or messing with the modal's html content are just hacks.

Comment: WIsh I could more upvotes :-) would have given least 10000

Answer (score 28):

What helped for me, was to put the following line in the ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    ..
    ...

    // codes works on all bootstrap modal windows in application
    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e)
    { 
        $(this).removeData();
    }) ;

    ...
    ..
});
```

When a modal window is closed and opened again, the previous entered and selected values, will be reset to the initial values.

I hope this will help you as well!

Comment: I have the same problem and when I used the approved answer all of the elements was gone just instead the data. This answer helped me a lot....

Comment: If the modal is remote (which is deprecated after bootstrap 3 so I advise to put modal-body inline) then you may have to tinker with how you reset the contents of the modal. For instance I have global `document.ready()` where I put this line of code there, but it doesn't reset my remote modals. What I did was use the approved answer but I put inside the remote modals `document.ready()`.

Comment: This is not working for me, how can I find the reason?

Comment: @Dinesh, I know this is like 5 years late, but the above uses jQuery, is it possible that you haven't loaded jQuery?

Answer (score 20):

Try cloning, then removing and re-adding the element when the modal is hidden. This should keep all events, though I haven't thoroughly tested this with all versions of everything.

```
var originalModal = $('#myModal').clone();
$(document).on('#myModal', 'hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal').remove();
    var myClone = originalModal.clone();
    $('body').append(myClone);
});
```

Comment: This solution works well with any kind of modification made to the modal content or layout: CSS classes, styles, dimensions and so on. +1 for the idea!

Comment: This solution is working in latest version `bootstrap@5.2.3` also.

Answer (score 12):

To reset all the input fields in a modal use the following.

```
$(".modal-body input").val("")
```

Comment: it woorks,but if there are input + select + textarea,we have to clear everyone

Comment: + if you have (I have) input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Save') then it will clear the value for the button too, so doesn't show name for button anymore. I added id for each input and had this script line for each input, script example: $("#firstInput").val('');

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative solution.

If you're doing a lot of changes to the DOM (add/removing elements and classes), there could be several things that need to be "reset." Rather than clearing each element when the modal closes, you could reset the entire modal everytime it's reopened.

Sample code:

```
(function(){

    var template = null

    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        if (template == null) {
            template = $(this).html()
        } else {
            $(this).html(template)
        }
        // other initialization here, if you want to
    })

})()
```

You can still write your initial state in HTML without worrying too much about what will happen to it later. You can write your UI JS code without worrying about having to clean up later. Each time the modal is relaunched it will be reset to the exact same state it was in the first time.

---

Edit: Here's a version that should handle multiple modals (I haven't tested it)...

```
(function(){

    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        if (!$(this).data('template')) {
            $(this).data('template', $(this).html())
        } else {
            $(this).html($this.data('template'))
        }
        // other initialization here, if you want to
    })

})()
```

Comment: The most flexible solution.

Answer (score 4):

That's works for me accurately

```
let template = null;
    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      template = $(this).html();
    });

    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
      $(this).html(template);
    });
```

Comment: this works for me special when u are using append not input.val.. thanks

Comment: @grace In my case it also worked for input where value attribute wasn't given.

Answer (score 3):

```
(function(){
        $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
            $(this).removeData();
        });
});
```

This is perfect solution to remove contact while hide/close bootstrap modal.

Comment: Out of all the solutions given above, this one works for me. Thanks vm!!

Answer (score 2):

also, you can clone your modal before open ;)

```
$('#myModal')
    .clone()
    .modal()
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset form elements ( Works with bootstrap 5 as well). Sample code :

```
$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", "#modalid", function () {
  $(this).find('#form')[0].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
     $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

It will remove all the data from the model and reset it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using BS 3.3.7 and i have a problem when i open a modal then close it, the modal contents keep on the client side no html("") no clear at all. So i used this to remove completely the code inside the modal div.
Well, you may ask why the padding-right code, in chrome for windows when open a modal from another modal and close this second modal the  stays with a 17px padding right.
Hope it helps...

```
$(document)
.on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { 
    $(document.body).addClass('modal-open') 
})
.on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { 
    $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open') 
    $(document.body).css("padding-right", "0px");
 $(this).removeData('bs.modal').find(".modal-dialog").empty();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
 $(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '#basicModal', function (e) {
        $('#basicModal').empty();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The below statements show how to open/reopen Modal  without using bootstrap.

Add two classes in css

And then use the below jQuery to reopen the modal if it is closed.

```
.hide_block
 {
   display:none  !important;
 }

 .display_block
 {
    display:block !important;
 } 

 $("#Modal").removeClass('hide_block');
 $("#Modal").addClass('display_block');
 $("Modal").show("slow");
```

It worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

/* this will change the HTML content with the new HTML that you want to update in your modal without too many resets... */

```
var = ""; //HTML to be changed 

$(".classbuttonClicked").click(function() {
    $('#ModalDivToChange').html(var);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BS 3.3.7

```js
$("#yourModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null); // will clear all element inside modal
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset form inside the modal. Sample Code:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', '#myModal', function (e) {
    $('#myModal form')[0].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To **reset/clear** all input fields from bootstrap modal use the following code:

```
$(".modal-body input").val("")
```

To **hide/close** bootstrap modal use the following code:

```
$('#yourModalId').modal('hide');
```

Keep Coding

Answer (score 0):

You should put the input you want inside the modal in a form and give an id to the close buttons then you should use this jquery --

`$(document).on('click', '#btnclose', function() { $("#Myform").trigger('reset'); $("#Mymodal").modal('hide'); });`

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question looking for an answer to clear all the Input fields in my modal when it is opened. None of the above does that effectively for me and they all use jQuery rather than straight JavaScript.

I used the following on mine to go get the Input fields from the modal's element and clear them all. I included two different snippets for adding an eventListener, one that will fire when a specific button is clicked, the other whenever the modal opens, regardless of the triggering element.

```
//This will fire when 'openButton' is clicked.
document.getElementById('openButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    ResetFormFields(GetInputChildren('newProductFields'));
});
    
//This will fire whenever myModal is shown regardless of what initiates it being shown            
document.getElementById('myModal').addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    ResetFormFields(GetInputChildren('newProductFields'));
});

function ResetFormFields(childrenArray){
    for (i=0; i<childrenArray.length; i++){
        childrenArray[i].value = "";
    }
}

function GetInputChildren(elementName){
    let children = Array.from(document.getElementById(elementName).children).filter((child) => {
        return child instanceof HTMLInputElement;
    });
    return children;
}
```