# JQuery .load function breaks other jQuery functions

Tags: jquery

```
function LoadModal(page, title) {
    title = title || '';

    $( "#modal_page" ).fadeIn("slow");
    $( "#modal_title" ).html(title);

    $("#modal_page_body").html('<h2 align="center">Loading...</h3><p align="center"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x"></i></p>'); //$('#LoadingDiv').show();
    $("#modal_page_body").load(page, function(){

    });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}
```

i have the above function in JQuery and i call it with this code:

```
<a href="#" onClick="LoadModal('/section/helpdesk/newticket', 'New Ticket');" title="New Ticket"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i></a>
```

Its working how i want it and the page is loading into the modal which is displaying fine.

However, when I close the Modal `$("#modal_page").fadeOut("slow")` any JQuery code on the main index.php page is not running. For example, I have a `.toggle` but that does not work. If i refresh the page, it then works fine until i open and close this modal again

Comment: I guess you have called jQuery lib file in your pop up page. So it's replacing the whole jQuery. Then after its gone jQuery has nothing. So, try removing jQuery from there. If not fixed then some code from that page will be helpful for us.

Comment: perfect - stick that as an answer and ill accept it :)

Comment: I think what you need to do is have the content in the modal refreshed while it's hidden. I have had a similar problem and this seemed to fix it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863003/how-to-reset-the-bootstrap-modal-when-it-gets-closed-and-open-it-fresh-again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have called jQuery lib file in your pop up page. So it's replacing the whole jQuery. Then after its gone jQuery has nothing. So, try removing jQuery from there.