# Modal Popup not clearing the fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal, modalpopup

I have used Twitter Bootstrap Modal popup for form. I have two buttons one is submit and close. If I click close button or 'x' button on top of popup is closing but if I open again The fields are not clearing as like in this

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnShowModal" runat="server" Text="+" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-info " data-target="#pnlModal1" data-toggle="modal"  OnClientClick="javascript:return false;" />
        <div id="pnlModal1" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div id="Div1" class="modal-content" runat="server">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Bank Details</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                            <div class="myform">
                                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Bank Name : </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBankName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="savebankdet" ControlToValidate="txtBankName" ErrorMessage="The Field is Required*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Account Name:</td>
                                                        <td class="aa" >
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAccName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="savebankdet" ControlToValidate="txtAccName" ErrorMessage="The Field is Required*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Account Number:</td>

                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAccNo" runat="server" ValidationGroup="savebankdet" ControlToValidate="txtAccNo" ErrorMessage="The Field is Required*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Country:</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCountry" runat="server" ValidationGroup="savebankdet" ControlToValidate="txtCountry" ErrorMessage="The Field is Required*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnAddBankAccount" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-info" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="savebankdet" OnClick="btnAddBankRecord_Click" />
                                                <button class="btn btn-info" id="btnbnkclose" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                                            </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: As like in given  fiddle fill and close 'x' and open again, the fields are not clearing    http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/RLQhh/

Comment: Hope this link will help you:
[How to reset the bootstrap modal when it gets closed and open it fresh again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863003/how-to-reset-the-bootstrap-modal-when-it-gets-closed-and-open-it-fresh-again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals shows an event for when a modal is hidden. Just tap into that:

```
$('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(this)
    .find("input,textarea,select")
       .val('')
       .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
       .prop("checked", "")
       .end();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5LCSU/

I would suggest the above as it bind the clearing to the modal itself instead of the close button, but I realize this does not address your specific question. You could use the same clearing logic bound to the dismiss buttons:

```
$('[data-dismiss=modal]').on('click', function (e) {
    var $t = $(this),
        target = $t[0].href || $t.data("target") || $t.parents('.modal') || [];

  $(target)
    .find("input,textarea,select")
       .val('')
       .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
       .prop("checked", "")
       .end();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jFyH2/

Comment: Hi Gohil this code can be useful if I use input, textarea tags html tags but here I am using Asp Controls like TextBox. I tried your code but it didn't worked

Comment: It doesn't mater if you are using ASP controls. It will work for asp controls also.

Comment: you can try with assign common class to all and then instead of input you can use class name in your jquery code. please try with this, it will work.

Comment: @Gohil it worked for me but it is not resetting the validation messages. Can you help me here

Answer (score 0):

you should use aomethind like this:

```
 $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863003/how-to-reset-the-bootstrap-modal-when-it-gets-closed-and-open-it-fresh-again

Comment: If I use that     $(".modal-body1").html("");    It will print empty Form.

Comment: you should reset form not modal body

Answer (score 0):

For reset your Bootstrap modal, you can do this **JS**

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function(){
   $(this).find('form')[0].reset(); /*Or reset your field with .val(' ') and .text(' ')*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear all the form fields within the bootstrap modal when pop-up is shown

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {$('#myform')[0].reset(); })
```

Since your code doesn't have a form tag shown,  you have to resort to clearing each and every input elements through script like below 
   `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {$('input [type="text"]').val("");})`

Answer (score 0):

try 
in aspx

```
<script>
function ModalClose() {
     $("#PanelModal").modal('hide');
}
</script>
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Close" ID="ButtonClose" OnClick="ButtonClose_Click" />
```

in aspx.cs

```
protected void ButtonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtBankName.Text = "";
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "ModalClose()", true);
}
```

this can be use without animation