# how to clear table data on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

[this is a pie,i want to click it show bootstrap modal and the modal content is a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ2SB.png)
[this is table data on modal when i click Pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUHsX.png)

i want to click the Pie to show bootstrap modal and show the table on modal,but when i first click it show right,when i second time to click it ,the table data on modal is still the first clicked show data,my question is how to clear teh table data,let me click it any time is a new data for show!  Thanks
i user this code ,but it dose not works.

```
  $("#showModal").on('hidden.bs.modal',function () {
                            $('#showModal').remove();
                             alert('Modal reset!');
                            });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863003/how-to-reset-the-bootstrap-modal-when-it-gets-closed-and-open-it-fresh-again

Comment: Yes, go ahead and use the above link given by @T.Shah which is perfect. You just have to clear the  html of modal body before hiding the modal like below `$(".modal-body").html("");`

Comment: i user it what you give me a link   but it still dose not works