# How can I use a bootstrap-modal multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How can I use a dynamically generated Bootstrap-Modal multiple times with a default state?

My problem is: When I click on the button to open the modal, you can see the default values 1 und 2. Now I enter '3' in the upper input field, close the modal with "Save changes" or "Close" and press the button again. Now, there should be 1 and 2 in the input fields but it's still 3 and 2.

I tried to fix it in jquery (as you can see in the code), but it did not work:

```js
    $('#openModal1').on('click', function(){
      let x = `
    <form class="modal fade" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-dialogLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-dialogLabel">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <!-- actual form markup -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="field1">Example label</label>
                      <input name="field1" type="text" value="1" class="form-control" id="field1" placeholder="Example input">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="field2">Another label</label>
                      <input name="field2" type="text" value="2" class="form-control" id="field2" placeholder="Another input">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /actual form markup -->

              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button id="save" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>    
    `;
      $("#modal-area").append(x);
      $('#modal-form').modal({});
    });

    $('#modal-form').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $("#modal-area").empty();
    });
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
    <div id="modal-area"></div>

    <button id="openModal1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-form">
      Open modal form
  </button>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863003/how-to-reset-the-bootstrap-modal-when-it-gets-closed-and-open-it-fresh-again)

Comment: You have to either *reset* the content or *reload*.  Depending on how you are generating it (backed), the size and complexity will determine the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `html()` not `append()` see below

```js
    $('#openModal1').on('click', function(){
      let x = `
    <form class="modal fade" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-dialogLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-dialogLabel">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <!-- actual form markup -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="field1">Example label</label>
                      <input name="field1" type="text" value="1" class="form-control" id="field1" placeholder="Example input">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="field2">Another label</label>
                      <input name="field2" type="text" value="2" class="form-control" id="field2" placeholder="Another input">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /actual form markup -->

              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button id="save" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>    
    `;
      $("#modal-area").html(x);
      $('#modal-form').modal({});
    });

    $('#modal-form').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $("#modal-area").empty();
    });
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
    <div id="modal-area"></div>

    <button id="openModal1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-form">
      Open modal form
  </button>
```