# Rails 5 Bootstrap modal duplicating previous window

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Modal setup where I have some JQuery adding content dynamically to each modal accordingly.  All works fine.

But there's one glitch I can't figure out.  So if any attribute, in this case, `link` is NOT present and I open the modal window (I'll call it window 1), it's blank - perfect.  But if I click and open a modal window that has a `link` attribute present (window 2), and then go back to click on the same previous window that had no link(window 1), it now shows a link - and the link it shows is from window 2.

I've checked in the console and I know that the `link.present?` is `false` - so I feel like it has something to do with JQuery needing to reset or something after I leave the `.hover` so it doesn't bind anymore.

Any thoughts anyone?

JQuery

```
$(".media").hover(function(){           
        var thisLink = $(this).find(".media-link").html();
        $("#media-modal-link").html(thisLink);
});
```

HTML (index.html.erb)

```
<% @media.each_slice(2).with_index do |(p,q), i| %>
    <% if p.link.present? %>
        <p class="media-link"> <%= link_to "Read More", p.link, target: "_blank" %></p>
    <% end %> 

    <% if q.link.present? %>
    <p class="media-link"> <%= link_to "Read More", q.link, target: "_blank" %></p>
<% end %>
```

_modal.html.erb

```
<div id="media-modal-link">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26864048/5551783

```
$("#media_modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
                $("#media-modal-link").html("");
              });
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to particularly let the hover function know which media-link to call. In this case you can use `id` to differentiate the media-link, instead of using `class='media-link'` you can use something like `id='media-link-1'` and `id='media-link-2'` and so on. Then use conditions in the hover function to show the media-link accordingly.

Comment: Could you explain the conditions part are provide some code?  Appreciate your help.