# How to Clear Modal Box DropDown and Text Box

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

How can I clear Modal Box after Submission of data Modal Box closes automatically but when we again open Modal Box it shows Previous submitted data.
I am Using Bootstrap Modal Box and C# Asp.net web forms.

Comment: add `$('.your-modal-class').hide();` change `.your-modal-class ` to your modal class, and add this code to `click` function that closes your modal

Comment: @20yco not for closing i m asking for clear previous Data

Comment: As of now, your question is too imprecise to be answered. Please [include your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset the bootstrap modal when it gets closed and open it fresh again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863003/how-to-reset-the-bootstrap-modal-when-it-gets-closed-and-open-it-fresh-again)

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the content at the time of modal hide.
For more detail follow this [How to reset the bootstrap modal when it gets closed and open it fresh again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863003/how-to-reset-the-bootstrap-modal-when-it-gets-closed-and-open-it-fresh-again)

Comment: hidden.bs.modal is an event occur when we hide model box. 
We can bind  the modal box clear with it

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    $(".modal-body1").html("");
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear all the field before closing or opening the Model box.

https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals shows an event for when a modal is hidden. Just tap into that:

Take a look on script to clear the input field or you have to do it from backends.

Comment: $('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(this)
    .find("input,textarea,select")
       .val('')
       .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
       .prop("checked", "")
       .end();
})