# Bootstrap modal does not update content and reset form in adminlte

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, bootstrap-modal, adminlte

When i open modal with data and close it and open again, **form** does not **reset** and show **old** data
how can i fix it and **initialize** form data?

I use bootstrap v3.3.7 and adminlte v2

modal html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="new" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="/image/loading.gif" class="loading"/>
                <span>Lodaing . . .</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

click on button:

```
<button href="/edit/id" data-target="#new" data-toggle="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
```

open modal content with **spring boot** cotroller:

```
@RequestMapping(value =  "/edit")
public String edit(Model model,
                   @ModelAttribute(value = "id") String paramId){


    if (paramId == 0){
        //open modal without data...
    }

    if (paramId != 0){
        //open modal with data...
    }


    model.addAttribute("edit", data);

    return "view/edit"; //open modal html template

}
```

Comment: show us your codes

Comment: Post your code. Check to see if your JS is requesting new data and updating your modal when you open it.

Comment: Refer the link, you get the way from your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863003/how-to-reset-the-bootstrap-modal-when-it-gets-closed-and-open-it-fresh-again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's obvious that your modal content remain on each time you open and close your modal, You should clear your modal content with the following code:

```js
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find(".modal-content").empty();
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button href="/edit/id" data-target="#new" data-toggle="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="new" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="/image/loading.gif" class="loading"/>
                <span>Lodaing . . .</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this in the javascript for your page, to clear the modal contents upon closing:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function (e) {
    // Handles the event thrown when a modal is hidden
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $(this).find(".modal-content").empty();
});
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?  The answer is correct.