# How to remove Modal's data-dismiss attribute using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am making a bootstrap modal. I want modal not to dismiss if I click a button when ajax response container errors.

```
<button class="btn btn-success mb-5 btn-md" type="submit" id="form_submit_1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agentForm2" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button>
```

I have tried this but it doesn't worked. Also checked bootstrap documentation but did not found any help.

```
 var modal1 = $('#form_submit_1'); 

 var data_dismiss = modal1.attr("data-dismiss");

 data_dismiss === "";
```

Is there any way to remove `data-dismiss` attribute using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/exx5e/ &&& https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863003/how-to-reset-the-bootstrap-modal-when-it-gets-closed-and-open-it-fresh-again

Comment: you are nearly there, you can set modal1.attr('data-dismiss','');

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this by

```
$("#form_submit_1").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
  alert('The modal is about to be hidden.');
  /** do your stuff here */
  return false;
});
```

You can see the full document here - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Preferred link - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_event_hide&stacked=h