# Destory CSS Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of data in a table and a button next to each row. When I click the buton, the modal loads up a relevant remote URL into the modal.

My submit button in said modal has the following jQuery attatched:

```
$('#editTrackModal').modal('hide');
```

When the modal hides, and I load up another remote URL into the modal, the modal appears, but on slower internet connections, the original content of the modal stays there for sometimes 4-5 seconds before being replaced.

Essentially, rather than hiding, I want to 'hide and destroy' the modal, and then re-create it.

Is this possible?

Simply destroying the modal after pressing the button closes the window, but then does not allow a subsequent modal to re-open until the page has reloaded.

Comment: Could you give us more code, how you load the remote URL?

Answer (score 0):

You could clean the content of the modal, before show, I dont know how you load the content, you could use something like this:

```
$("#editTrackModal .modal-body").empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do like this

```js
// the modal is distroyed on hide event..
$('#editTrackModal').on('hidden', function(){
    $(this).data('modal', null); //this will destroy you data and model means it will reset.
});
```

and it may be duplicate of **[how to destroy bootstrap modal window completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177426/how-to-destroy-bootstrap-modal-window-completely)**

you can refer to that link also.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to ensure that the modal's content is clean after hiding/closing it is can be done like this:

```
$('#editTrackModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#editTrackModal div').remove(); //When the hidden event is triggered, remove all the contents of the modal.
});
```

And when you want to `show` the modal again, you can do something like this:

```
$('#editTrackModal').append($('.modal-contents')); //create first the contents of the modal, then attach it.
$('#editTrackModal').modal('show');
```

Your html may look like this:

```
<div id="editTrackModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class='modal-contents'>
        ......Build your modal contents here......
    </div>
</div>
```